# How do I know if an installed driver was obtained from Windows Update?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Is there anyway to know if a driver was obtained from Windows Update on Windows 7?

Comment: Why are you worried about "the current drive", If the device works, that's all that should matter.  The only device driver you should worry about updating is the display driver, and that's only because, you go through Nvidia and AMD for that.

Comment: @Ramhound No that 
isn't all that should matter.  If you don't know where a driver came from, and it works, this could potentially be an issue, because it might be a modified version of what you need; I'm concerned about security.  If that wasn't a problem why would drivers have to be signed?

Comment: Enter device manager, pick your device properties, go to the driver tab, look at who signed the driver, not 100% but as close as you can get. As far as I can tell drivers installed by windows update will be signed "Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Publisher"

Answer (score -1):

Open Windows Update, then click on "View Installed Updates", then look for your driver there. If it is there, then it was installed with Windows Update.